# Facebook login with existing system Mysql table structure

Tags: php, mysql, facebook-login

I have made a Mysql login system for my website with a structure like below:

```
id | name         | email           | pass              | status(Y/N)  | token
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | Alex         | xxxx@gmail.com  | $2y$10$4BSz5Bqr6x | Y            | 53f10977b14f752
```

Wheres id is a primary key and authorization is made with unique email and password. User gets confirmation letter after registration with token filled link to my website. Clicking the link changes user's status from N to Y.

I want to let people use "Login with facebook" option to login my website. What kind of table should I make for facebook logins (perhaps in the future also Google+)? I don't prefer forcing them to make account for my website if they decide to use facebook login but to let them use the website with only facebook credentials if they choose so. I think it would be wise to store facebook id's on the other table and later give them an option to merge both accounts in case of double registration or if they want to "Connect with facebook" after creating normal account on my website.

Still, all the accounts: normal, facebook, google+(?) should be somehow connected to the same table to let all have unique primary key ids because users can post rides for carpooling and I need to identify which user owns the ride.

Comment: This is going to need some more code for context here otherwise it's not really possible to explain this in specific terms.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. Many of these have native support for Oauth, as used by Facebook, Twitter, Google and others, which means integration is as easy as setting flags.

Comment: You will need to do a lot more research on what data you can obtain from each source. With that information you can judge how your table structure should be. However I would have to agree with @tadman. Why work hard if you can work smarter? Find a framework that handles Oauth and such. Don't try and create your own.